# clang: warning: -l*: 'linker' input unused

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I compile code using GNU Make I get multiple warnings like:

```
clang: warning: -lGui: 'linker' input unused
```

This is probably because I have messed something up in my Makefile (below). Can anyone point me toward the problem?

```
CXX=g++
CC=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -W -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings $(shell root-config --cflags --glibs)
CPPFLAGS+=-MMD -MP
LDFLAGS=-g $(shell root-config --ldflags)
LDLIBS=$(shell root-config --libs)

xSec_x: xSec_x.o xSec.o Analysis.o
-include xSec_x.d xSec.d Analysis.d

xSec.o: xSec.cpp xSec.h Analysis.h Analysis.cpp

xSec_x.o: xSec_x.cpp xSec.h Analysis.h

clean:
    rm -f @rm -f $(PROGRAMS) *.o *.d
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That message means you are passing linker flags (like `-l` which tells the linker to pull in a library) to the compiler.

This means that the result of running `root-config --cflags --glibs` is generating linker flags, and those are going into `CXXFLAGS`, which is being passed to the compiler.  I don't know what `root-config` is, but you should investigate its command line and invoke it in a way where it doesn't generate linker flags.  Probably removing the `--glibs` option will do it.

ETA: you *really* want to be using `:=` to assign these flags variables if you're going to run `$(shell ...)` there.  It will work either way, but if you use `=` then the shell command will be run *every time make expands the variable*, which is once per compilation.  If you use `:=` it will only be run once, when the makefile is parsed.

Comment: D'oh! I was passing all the linker flags to the compiler... I wish clang was a little more descriptive. The error makes it sound like the lib was ignored because the code never used its symbols.

Answer (score 7):

I got this same error and the reason was that I forgot to add `-I` in front of my included paths for cflags in makefile. For example:

```
CFLAGS += $(path)/dir/subdir/include     -> Got the above mentioned error.
CFLAGS += -I$(path)/dir/subdir/include   -> Fixed the issue.
```